# DB setup (use of 1 contact table for multiple tables)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

The question below is related, but no answer is provided:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104820/single-contact-table-for-multiple-entities

I have a contact table which has columns: id(PK), phone1, phone2, email1, email2, fax1, fax2

I also have 3 other tables: SUPPLIER, PERSON and CLIENT

I want to use this 1 contact table in my 3 other tables. Simple by using the CONTACT.id as a FK in my 3 other tables.

Problem with this approach is that our business rules require a SUPPLIER and CLIENT to always have a phone1(NULL is not allowed). However a PERSON does not have to have a phone1(NULL is allowed here).

So what's the best solution here? (I have some possible solutions in mind but want to know the opinion of others)

Comment: Keep the field nullable in database. Based on the roles, validate the contact info, before submitting in your `View`.

Comment: Marianogs answer is an option but I have used this option to implement, it's a good one, thnx

Comment: it's the method I choice so you can post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the field nullable in database. Based on the roles, validate the contact info, before submitting in your `View`.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the column phone1 from table CONTACT to tables SUPPLIER, PERSON and CLIENT.
You can leave other columns on table CONTACT.